# Recently added attribute doesn't appear in DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I set an attribute from "mounted" hook with js on Vue.js

```js
document.getElementById("MF TYPE_U32").lastChild.firstChild.setAttribute("name", "123");
```

When I going to Inspector I don't see any changes in the attribute list.
On inspector, the relevant element looks :

```
<div id="MF TYPE_U32" class="row my-1 key">
     <div class="text_aln_rht col-sm-5">
           <label for="2797993984">Carrier Frequency</label>
     </div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
     <input type="text" placeholder="GHz" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="__BVID__147"> <i class="fas fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Did anybody face this issue?

Comment: Can we see the relevant HTML?

Comment: your last child is parent to any dom?

Comment: Add  complete DOM for better solution

Comment: Added the whole block.  Thanks

Comment: "id" attribute values cannot contain spaces.

Comment: are  you sure `firstChild` isn't a `#text` node ? see maybe: `node.firstElementChild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
document.getElementById("MF TYPE_U32").lastElementChild.firstElementChild.setAttribute("name", "123");
```